# After new Ubuntu server installations sometimes Nano is highlighting text and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: nano

After new Ubuntu server installations sometimes Nano is highlighting text and sometimes it doesn't.

I pay for a hosting provider that let me install new VPSs in a few clicks. I usually Install Ubuntu 16.04 VPSs and then tunnel into them from local Ubuntu.

### My question:

I usually create a file in nano, paste in a ready script, and execute.

Why does sometime the syntax of the script is highlight and sometimes it doesn't?

For example, say I created 2 VPSs:

In one the script content is highlighted only in White and in another different parts have different colors like in the picture below:

I ask why, why it's like that only in some installations but not in all of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nano 2.5.3 cannot "guess" what is the language I code in. If I just execute `nano` and then paste in a script content, it will all be white (or the default general text color for the editor).

If I paste this command:

```
nano ~/ses.sh && chmod +x ~/ses.sh && bash ~/ses.sh && rm ~/ses.sh
```

Then the syntax will be highlighted accordingly to the file extension (in this case `.sh`).

Until a few minutes I didn't know that actually doing `nano filename.extension` (like `nano ses.sh`) is what making nano to use the specific styling. I didn't know it's associated but now I've learned that.

Note: If you used a similar script creation process and still didn't have the color it might be due to a bug or partial stuckage of your TTY (that is, in simple words, terminal window) and starting a new session should fix that.